# Sitecore Search Scope Boosting - 400 Bad request

Tags: sxa, solr, sxa-search, boosting

I have created a search scope that works very well. But I would like to make the search box to search the items based on the field value. So I add a new rule in the boosting section and it throws a 400 bad request error to me. Can someone help me? Thanks.

**Search Scope**
[image: Example Scope]

**Error**
[image]

**Error Response**
[image]

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: hello @MichaelWest Here is the version. Sitecore.NET 9.3.0 (rev. 003498)